# Usage of the noun invest beyond meteorology

Tags: word-usage, abbreviations

The noun *invest* appears to be in use as a short form of *investigative area* in meteorology [1]. I recently heard several nonnative speakers use it in a financial context as a short form of *investment*. Is this common among native speakers?

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invest_(meteorology)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Invest* as a noun was listed as obsolete by OED in 1900.

> A payment made to the Pope or Head of the church by a bishop or the like at his investiture.
>
> > 1533–4   Act 25 Hen. VIII c. 20 §1   Yeldyng vnto the kinges highnes..all suche dueties, rightes, and inuestes, as before time hath ben accustomed to be paid for any such Archbishopricke or Bishopricke.

Using it as meaning *investment* could be a form of nounifying the verb (“It’s a big **ask** to make such an **invest**”), but it’s more likely simply to be jargon or slang, shortening the long word *investment* in much the same way as a specification is often referred to as a *spec* [pronounced *speck*].

Ngrams don't have any data for [*invest* as a noun](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=invest_NOUN&direct_url=), which would either mean that it’s very recent or that the usage has never appeared in English publications. That non-appearance may be due to its being a foreign-English construct, or that it’s too recent to have caught on for print.